# How to show find results in separate tab or window?

Tags: find, sublimetext2

I started using Sublime Text 2 coming from Notepad++.

I cannot find a way to show the find results in a separate space (tab,window,sidebar whatever).

In notepad++ i had a little window showing the line where the string was found. I then could double click to go to the line.

I cant do that in Sublime. I press <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> type my string and press <kbd>Find All</kbd>.

I have indication that x results found and can loop through them, but i cant make it open a separate space for them.

Also the Find results submenu in Find menu is grayed out.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, there are a few ways to use search in sublime. What you are doing is searching in the current file you have open <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

What I *think* you want to do is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> - then type your string and click 'find' – that will open a results panel in a new window/pane and you can click on the highlighted results to jump you to the place in that file.

Comment: It worked once...:) I tried it in an XML file , but it doesnt work on .LOG text files..Getting 0 results !..I dont have anythign in exclude

Comment: Are you definitely putting a location in the 'Where' field? If that field is now empty you won't get any results.

Comment: In html, txt,xml e.t.c files even if i dont put anything in the where it brings up the search results...in .log it doesn't bring anything up even if i specifically say "open files"

Comment: Only other thought I have is to check you don't have the regular expression, case sensitive etc buttons selected on the left of the search box

Comment: Nope. opened another question for this. thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545505/sublime-search-find-in-files-doesnt-always-work

Comment: Results panel is empty if you are searching from open cache files.

Answer (score 53):

Searching With <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Sublime 3 will bring the search results in a `separate pane at bottom`.

In case you want it in a **separate tab** along side other tabs and also want to see the ***previous results cached*** above the current one, check the button on left side that says - **" Use Buffer "**

. You will see the button on left side when you open the Find and Replace panel with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for this I had had the results in a new tab until recently they started going to a bottom panel and I could not figure out how to get them back into a tab. Your answer helped - this is not obvious.

Comment: I actually wanted to do the opposite, stop the results from being in a separate tab, so this is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else found this answer from the same web search as I did, and they want to **jump to results** in a separate tab, after they've done a `control-shift-F` search:

From the menu bar, click **Preferences**, then click **Settings**.

This will open a new sublime window with a pair of open files.
On one side (usually the left view) is a file named something like

```
C:\Users\YourNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings
```

with tons of stuff in it.

On the other side, you'll see a file named something like

```
C:\Users\YourNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\Default\Preferences.sublime-settings
```

which is mostly empty.

Inside that mostly-empty file, add this line

```
"find_in_files_side_by_side": true,
```

so that it's inside any braces there.
Save this file, and the change should take effect immediately.

For example, my file looks like this:

```
{
    "font_size": 18,
    // Open search results from find in files buffer side-by-side.
    "find_in_files_side_by_side": true,
}
```