# Sublime search "Find in Files" doesn't always work

Tags: search, sublimetext2

The EXACT same thing if i do it in .html , xml files e.t.c it works as it should. That is it reutrns a filled find results tab. In this file it doesn't

I have a simple .log text file

When i search with <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> everything is ok:

[image: Normal search]

when i use <kbd>ctrl+shift+f</kbd> i have 0 results. Why?

[image: findinfiles1]

[image]

Comment: Well what is CTRL + SHIFT + F supposed to do differently?

Comment: I am doing the SAME with another file and it returns FIND RESULTS tab as it should....Why it doesnt do it in this file for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanning through the text of these log files, do you see any control characters?  According to [this answer](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-search-find-in-files-doesnt-always-work/14021/2) to your question in the Sublime Text forum, when Sublime Text finds inline control characters, Find in Files will treat the whole file as binary and therefore not display detailed results.

**TL;DR: Try deleting control characters.**